# Loading resources like JQuery and JQuery UI from CDN

Tags: jquery, grails, resources, cdn

I am using grails resources 1.1.6 and I am able to load a library from an external host, e.g by doing:

```
modules = {

    jquery_cdn {
        resource(disposition: "head", url:'js/jquery.mobile-1.7.1.js', linkOverride:'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js')
    }
[..]
}
```

Hoewever, as soon as I add jquery-ui in here, it stops working and it resolves the file from the current host.

```
modules = {
    jquery_cdn {
        resource(disposition: "head", url:'js/jquery.mobile-1.7.1.js', linkOverride:'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js')
        resource(disposition: "head", url:'js/something', linkOverride:'http://anything')
    }
[..]
}
```

This results in:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script src="/static/XMKHDE4MFb89NXoDjkyRQnfxc1eyN63e6j43EEfPshE.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
```

What the hell am i doing wrong?

Comment: Any solution for this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
modules = {
    ...
    streetmap {
        resource url: 'http://www.openlayers.org/api/OpenLayers.js', disposition: 'head'
        resource url:'js/streetmap.js'
    }
    ...
}
```

where js/streetmap.js contains my additional functions

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use the overrite closure to redefine an existing resource. jquery ui uses the key "jquery" as dependency. To "globally" overrite this key use:

```
def jqver = org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.jquery.JQueryConfig.SHIPPED_VERSION

// ...

// setup cdn as overrite for jquery libs
overrides {
    jquery {
        resource id:'js', url: "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/${jqver}/jquery.min.js",
                disposition:'head', nominify: true
    }

    'jquery-ui' {
        resource id:'js', url: "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/${jqver}/jquery-ui.min.js",
                disposition:'head', nominify: true
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You may want to check this out:
http://code.google.com/apis/libraries/devguide.html

You can load in jQuery and the jQuery-UI plugin with this.

Comment: The question is not how to include JQ from google, but how to configure grails resource plugin to include those.